# Filter records by Wild Card

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, wildcard, sql-like

I have a very simple Stored Procedure that filter rows using the `Wild Card` My question is Why doesn't the Wild card return specific row?

For Example I have following entries:

```
ID  Name           Price
1   rose pink      20
2   dark rose      63 
3   rose pink New  40
4   black Velvet   30
```

If I say

`select * from Product 
where Name like '%rose%'`

It will return first three rows. Fine

But when I say

`select * from Product 
where Name like '%rose pink%'`

It must return first row only but what the `wild card` does is, It returns third row as well. So my question is, how to make the `sp` to be able to return all rows if a generic term is used like `rose`.At the same time I want my `sp` to return only that row whose name matches completely with the passed parameter

**EDIT**
Here is the store procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_Get_Products]                                 
@rvcName varchar(50),                                                                
as                                
begin  
   select * from Product where Name Like '%'+ @rvcName +'%'   
end
```

Comment: have you tried a negation? `where like '%foo%' and not like '%foo bar'` ?

Comment: I need a more general solution that I can use. My example is simple with hardcoded values for `Like` but I am looking for a solution that would filter records by wild card as well as specific

Comment: rose pink should be like '%rose pink' for you to get results

Comment: @tinka I want my `sp` to be able to return all rows if a generic term is used like `rose`.At the same time I want my `sp` to return only that row whose name matches completely with the passed parameter

Comment: @HumaAli then you have to tell SP

Comment: @tinka Edited my post

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. Like is used to search for something in something. For completely match you have to use =

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
IF EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM Product
           WHERE Name = @rvcName
           )

SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE Name = @rvcName

ELSE 

SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE Name LIKE '%'+ @rvcName +'%'
```

Comment: yes, sorry, copy and pasted answer, untested. Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, how to make the sp to be able to return all rows if
> a generic term is used like rose.At the same time I want my sp to
> return only that row whose name matches completely with the passed
> parameter

The answer is that you have to instruct your sp to either use `Like` or `=`.
When you use `Like` typically you search for something that starts with, ends with or contains the text you provide.

So your options, for example, searching for `rose` are:

1. find all rows that match rose `name = 'rose'` (`name like 'rose'`)
2. find all rows that starts with rose `name like 'rose%'`
3. find all rows that contains rose `name like '%rose%'`
4. find all rows that ends with rose `name like '%rose'`

There is no way to combine 1 and 3 in a "generic" form.

#### Final thought:

Consider using `Full Text` instead of `Like`.